# How to Properly Convert String with \u{xx} in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, encoding

I have String that prints out things like \u{1B}. Is it because it's not properly encoded? If so, how do I convert them so that it prints out right characters? I tried to convert the string into Data using utf8 and convert it back to String using .utf8, but it still prints \u{...}. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you print a string or collection (e.g. dictionary) which *contains* a string? In the latter case it is just the dictionary description method which escapes all non-ASCII characters, and don't need to care.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR for help. I'm not sure, but this is String from NSEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers. Reference says the declaration is "var charactersIgnoringModifiers: String? { get }"

Comment: That's an *optional* string for which (I think) the same applies. Try `print(charactersIgnoringModifiers!)` or `print(charactersIgnoringModifiers ?? "")` – And what output do you expect? `\u{1B}` is the Escape character.